# Is it possible to use Senenium without driver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I want to use selenium in the spyder/Jupyter-notebook, but I can not download the driver. Is it possible to somehow use selenium without download the driver, like in collab version

Comment: Can not download the driver because of a work restriction thing with executable files? Or do you mean you literally can't download it (technical issues)?

Comment: The computer where I want to run this code, it is denied

Comment: If you used Java I think there is a way around this via Maven/POM files but I am not sure in Python.  Hopefully someone else chimes in with a solution.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is a tool that mainly enables and supports automation of web browsers. Therefore, it does require a web driver at the back-end. From the [docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/selenium_installation/):

> To use Selenium in your automation project you need to install the language bindings libraries for your language of choice. In addition you will need WebDriver binaries for the browsers you want to automate and run test on.

Moreover, looking at the [repo](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py) you can see that it does require a driver depending on which browser you plan to use.

If you cannot install a driver because of policy restrictions, speak to your admin and explain why you need it; they might be able to install it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can user `Remote` driver if you don't want to run it locally. For example you can run it on aws device farm.Here is an example on how to do it if you want to do it on aws device farm:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/testgrid/testing-frameworks-python.html

```
import boto3
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver import Remote
class MyPytestTests():
  def setup_method(self, method):
    devicefarm_client = boto3.client("devicefarm")
        testgrid_url_response = devicefarm_client.create_test_grid_url(
        projectArn= "arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:111122223333:testgrid-project:123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000",
      expiresInSeconds=300
      )
     desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
     desired_capabilities["platform"] = "windows"
     self.driver = Remote(testgrid_url_response['url'], desired_capabilities)
```

and for teardown:

```
   def teardown_method(self, method):
    self.driver.quit()
```

(excerpt from aws docs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use headless approach to run selenium.
https://dev.to/googlecloud/using-headless-chrome-with-cloud-run-3fdp